# How to Get Mathematica to Recognize a Three-Finger Trackpad Click?

Tags: eventhandler

The following code allows me to change the **size** of a disk back and forth with a **one-finger trackpad click**, and change the **color** of a disk back and forth with a **two-finger trackpad click**.

```
DynamicModule[{col = Green, size = 1}, 
 EventHandler[
  Graphics[{Dynamic@col, Disk[{0, 0}, Dynamic@size]}, 
   PlotRange -> 2],
  {
{"MouseDown", 
     1} :> (size = size /. {1 -> 2, 2 -> 1}), 
{"MouseDown", 
     2} :> (col = col /. {Red -> Green, Green -> Red})}]]
```

[image]

I'd like to be able to do a three-finger click to do something else.  For example, a three-finger click might change the shape back and forth between a square and a disk. I can't figure out how to get Mathematica to recognize a three-finger click. Using "MouseDown"->3 does not work.

Any ideas?